# Does a metric exist for the surface defined by $0=\phi^2t^4-x^2-y^2-z^2$?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, space-expansion, topology

I have a surface defined by the quadratic relation:$$0=\phi^2t^4-x^2-y^2-z^2$$Where $\phi$ is a constant with units of $km$ $s^{-2}$, $t$ is units of $s$ (time) and x, y and z are units of $km$ (space).  The surface (ignoring one of the dimensions of space) looks like this:

[image: Surface of Quadratic Expansion]

Since the formula depends on the absolute value of $t$, is it possible to create a metric?  If so, what would the metric be (it seems to me that the metric would have to be a function of time such that $ds^2(t)=<some expression>$).

Comment: related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2591095/

Comment: Is this not just describing a ray of light where the time is scaled by some factor $\phi$, i.e. $t' = \phi t$ gives $t'^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 0$ with metric $(1,-1,-1,-1)$ so that you can say $(\phi,-1,-1,-1)$ is the metric?

Comment: You can always use the [induced metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric). It may just not be the optimal choice.

Comment: what do you mean by "is it possible to create a metric"? given a (reasonably smooth) surface, you can generically put many different metrics on it. Where's the physics here?

Comment: @bolbteppa Note the $t^4$, instead of $t^2$.  That's evidently intentional, and not a typo, given the OP's description of $\phi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at an embedded submanifold,<sup>(*)</sup> and it sounds like you're asking for the [metric that is induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric) by restricting the metric of the larger space — which apparently has coordinates $t, x, y, z$ — onto the submanifold.  [This is what @marmot was saying in the comments on the question.]  Of course, the answer depends on the metric of the larger space, but I'm guessing that you assume the larger space has a Minkowski metric:
\begin{equation}
  ds^2_{l} = c^2 dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2.
\end{equation}
If you dislike this signature, feel free to just flip all the signs here and in the result below.  Also remember that there's another branch of the solution with negative values for $t$, which is not shown in your diagram.

To simplify the algebra, let's back up and define a *different* set of coordinates $t, r, \vartheta, \varphi$ on the larger manifold.  In that case, the surface is defined implicitly by the equation
\begin{equation}
  0 = \phi^2 t^4 - r^2,
\end{equation}
and the original metric in these coordinates is just
\begin{equation}
  ds^2_{l} = c^2 dt^2 - dr^2 - r^2 d\vartheta^2 - r^2 \sin^2 \vartheta d\varphi^2.
\end{equation}
(This is basically the familiar metric in spherical coordinates, plus the time term.)

Now, your equation implicitly defines the surface, but it doesn't define coordinates to use in parametrizing that surface.  Since there's just one equation and the larger manifold is four-dimensional, we know that your submanifold is three-dimensional (except at $t=0$), so we hope to be able to use three coordinates to parametrize it everywhere.  Indeed, away from $t=0$, we can basically use $t, \theta, \phi$.  It might be a little clearer to define the new coordinates $T, \Theta, \Phi$ *on* the surface, even though the most obvious definition for these coordinates will give them very simple relationships to the original coordinates.  Now we can give the surface in the larger space in terms of these three coordinates by this expression:
\begin{align}
  t &= T, \\
  r &= \phi T^2, \\
  \vartheta &= \Theta, \\
  \varphi &= \Phi.
\end{align}
The $t, \vartheta, \varphi$ expressions are basically definitions, whereas the $r$ expression is a consequence of those three definitions and your definition of the surface.

Next, we can use the expression from [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric) to find the induced metric:
\begin{align}
  ds^2_{s}
  &=
  \left[c^2 - \left( \frac{\partial r} {\partial T} \right)^2 \right] dT^2 - \phi^2 T^4 d\Theta^2 - \phi^2 T^4 \sin^2 \Theta d\Phi^2 \\
  &=
  \left[c^2 - 4 \phi^2 T^2 \right] dT^2 - \phi^2\, T^4\, d\Theta^2 - \phi^2\, T^4\, \sin^2 \Theta\, d\Phi^2.
\end{align}
This result aligns with the intuition that the metric should "depend on time", even though it is explicitly given only in terms of the intrinsic coordinates on the submanifold.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Actually, there's a little problem at $t=0$, where your "submanifold" pinches off.  This disqualifies it from even being a differentiable manifold.  But let's just ignore that point, because everything works properly everywhere else.  You have a true metric singularity at that point anyway.

Comment: Mike, that appears to be an amazing solution.  It's going to take me some time to unpack it given my limited skills but this (appears) to be what I'm looking for.  I've got a follow-up question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378958/what-is-the-curvature-of-this-shape-is-it-closed

Comment: safesphere (on the follow up thread) pointed out that the metric becomes spacelike at $T=\frac{1}{2\phi}$ yet I don't see that when I look at the original shape.  This shape appears to be spacetime out to infinity (and beyond).

Comment: That's correct.  You can see this from your diagram because the "trumpet" is getting broader and broader quickly — so quickly that it eventually becomes flatter than the light cones of the underlying spacetime.  So yes, after that time, there is no timelike direction *in* your submanifold.  I'm not saying that this has anything to do with physics, but that's what your submanifold does.

Comment: @Mike The OP really should better explain the physical motivation for his question. The fact that his spacetime expands faster than light may have two meanings. One, as we assumed, is that this soacetime all becomes spacelike. However, this is true only if the embedding space is flat. The other meaning that seem more natural is that the speed of light evolves with time. In this case, this spacetime never becomes all spacelike, but then the embedding space is not Minkowski.

Comment: @safesphere - The former - all spacetime becomes spacelike.  That is, the  visible universe (outside your galaxy) effectively disappears after 245 billion years.  I just disagreed on the timing, $\frac {1}{2\phi}$ vs. $\frac {c}{2\phi}$.

Comment: I'm happy to take this opportunity to remove the bad original version of my answer and streamline everything, while inserting the relevant factors of $c$.

Comment: @safesphere - I understand what you're saying, but I don't understand the discrepancy yet.  I need a little more time to digest Mike's formula and reconcile that against what I've done using the original shape formula.  I'm not ready to put c in yet.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury the visible universe does not disappear beyond your galaxy. Instead the whole universe ceases to exist at that point in time, including your galaxy.

Comment: @Mike - Please don't, just yet.  I think we all agree there's some point where this expansion becomes spacelike.  I need a little more time to think about the metric.  Thank you for the offer.

Comment: Oh, I already did it.  I really think it's better this way.  But if you want to see the old version, click on the thing at the bottom of the answer that says "edited [n] minutes ago", and you can look through older revisions.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the total proper time of an observer at constant $\Theta, \Phi$ coordinates really is finite in this submanifold.  You can just plug my result in to [this equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time#cite_ref-12) and [see that it can only ever be finite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%5BSqrt%5B1+-+T%5E2%5D,+%7BT,+0,+1%7D%5D) while the manifold is nonsingular and has a timelike direction.