# What is the curvature of this shape? Is it closed?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, space-expansion, topology

This is a follow up question to this [issue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377946/does-a-metric-exist-for-the-surface-defined-by-0-phi2t4-x2-y2-z2/378408?noredirect=1#comment848073_378408).  I have the following metric:$$\mathrm{d}s_s^2=[1-4\phi^2T^2]\mathrm{d}T^2-\phi^2T^4\mathrm{d}\Theta^2-\phi^2T^4\sin^2\Theta \mathrm{d}\Phi^2$$
Where $\phi$ is a constant in units of $km$ $s^{-2}$ (length per square time), $\Phi$ and $\Theta$ are 3D polar coordinates and $T$ is time. What is the curvature of this space at time, $T$?

If I travel in a straight line in the space defined by this metric and travel long enough, will I end up back where I started (is it closed)?

Comment: What type of curvature are you seeking to compute? (Riemann, Ricci tensor, Ricci scalar)?

Comment: The unit in your formula does not match the dimentionaliry that you have defined for $\phi$ and time.

Comment: $\phi^2T^4$ should reduce to square space ($km^2$).  I'm having trouble seeing where you think the dimensional analysis isn't right.

Comment: @safesphere I'm talking about geodesics.  Would they be closed in this space?

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli - I'm not sure.  If I project this shape onto Minkowski (3D) space and look at a far distant object, like CMB, would I be able to measure positive, negative or zero curvature?  Intuitively it feels like some function of time, such that $C(T) = <some curvature value>$ and I'm hoping it's approaches zero with time.

Comment: In square brackets you have a dimensionless unity minus a dimensional value.

Comment: That makes sense, but would you please go to the original answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377946/does-a-metric-exist-for-the-surface-defined-by-0-phi2t4-x2-y2-z2/378408?noredirect=1#comment848073_378408 and raise the issue on the thread where Mike worked this out?  Thanks!

Comment: Your spacelike geodesics are spirals, so they are not closed in spacetime. Also from $T=\dfrac{1}{2\phi}$ your spacetime becomes space only with no time and open. Before that it is closed and is expanding with acceleration.

Comment: Set what is in square brackets to zero.

Comment: @safesphere - yes, I got that.  Sorry I didn't delete the question before you saw it and responded.