# How can I trace the path of a photon on space-time defined by this metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

I have a hypothetical universe where the relation between space and time is defined by this metric:

$$ds^2=-\phi^2dt^4+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$
Where $\phi = 1.94 \times 10^{-14}\space km\space s^{-2}$ (note that all terms are rank-2 differential form).  Ignoring one of the dimensions of space, the surface of this space-time looks like this:
[image: Hypothetical Universe after 6 months]

I would like to describe how a photon of light travelling at c would travel on this surface, but I lack the basic skills to perform the operation using differential geometry.  Note that the size of the universe is accelerating with the passage of time.  I know it can be done using integration, geometry and a lot of algebra, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to solve it using the metric.

My question is, if I know the current time and the amount of time the photon has been travelling at c, can I calculate the amount of space it's traveled?

Comment: Are you sure your time component is in the 4th power rather than squared? Also with $\phi$ measured in $km/s^2$ the dimensionality of your metric does not add up.

Comment: Indeed, as you were told on [mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179898/34893), your $\mathrm ds^2$ is not a metric. The first term makes no sense: it is a rank-4 form, and a metric must be rank-2. Also, the level-sets you are plotting are meaningless: there is no such a thing as "the surface of [a] space-time". And what you are plotting, the level sets $\phi t^4=\vec r^2$, have nothing to do with your metric: $\mathrm dt^4\neq t^4,\ \mathrm dr^2\neq \vec r^2$. May I suggest trying to revise the basic concepts of GR? Any introductory book should work.

Comment: related by OP: [Does a metric exist for the surface defined by $0=\phi^2t^4-x^2-y^2-z^2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377946/84967).

Comment: @safesphere - Perhaps I'm missing something, doesn't the term $\phi^2 dt^4$ have units of $km^2$ just like the rest of the terms.  Why is the dimensionality off?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I missed that $\phi$ was squared. Still $\phi dt^4$ is rank-4 and must be changed to rank-2 to work, something like $\phi t^2 dt^2$.

Comment: @safesphere - to be clear, I think we want $\phi^2 t^2 dt^2$.  Dimensionally, that's the only way I can arrive at a $km^2$ term that can be added to the other spacial terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your metric must be corrected to be rank-2. Evidently you are trying to write a metric for the universe expanding with the acceleration $\phi$  $$\,r\sim \phi t^2$$

Your corrected metric equation would be

$$ds^2=-\phi^2t^2dt^2+dr^2$$

Where

$$dr^2\equiv dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$

Null geodesics (trajectories of light) would be found by setting $\,ds=0$

$$r=\dfrac{\phi}{2}(t-t_o)^2$$

As you can easily see, for $\phi=0$ time in this universe stops. A better metric is

$$ds^2=-(\phi t+c)^2dt^2+dr^2$$

With the trajectories of light given by

$$r=c(t-t_o)+\dfrac{\phi}{2}(t-t_o)^2$$

Where $r(t_o)$ and $t_o$ are the coordinates of the light emission event and the negative solution is dropped as the time reversal. The coordinate distance $r$ traveled by light is

$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

**EDIT based on OP's requirements in the comments**

> The features that need to be captured are
>
> A) $x=\phi t^2$ (the diameter of the universe is proportional to the square of the time)
>
> B) The space is closed (travel far enough in a straight line and you arrive where you started)
>
> C) A metric that can be compared to FLRW, and hopefully one that provides a differential solution for the path of a photon

We start with a generic metric for an expanding space assuming its homogeneity and isotropy

$$ ds^2 = - c^2 dt^2 + a(t)^2 d\mathbf{\Sigma}^2 $$

Where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ ranges over a 3-dimensional space of a uniform positive curvature and $a(t)$ is a scale factor. According to the requirement (A) where $\phi$ is acceleration

$$ r=\dfrac{\phi}{2}t^2$$

While the topology of this space may vary, the requirement (B) along with OP's comments and chart imply that the space is a 3-sphere $S^3$ whose round metric in the hyperspherical coordinates is

$$ d\mathbf{\Sigma}^2=r^2 d\mathbf{\Omega}^2 $$

Where

$$ d\mathbf{\Omega}^2=d\psi^2 + \sin^2\psi\left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\, d\varphi^2\right) $$

Combining the formulas we obtain the final metric

$$ ds^2 = - c^2 dt^2 + (\dfrac{\phi}{2}t^2)^2 d\mathbf{\Omega}^2 $$

The null geodesics equation is $ds=0$ or for $\theta=\varphi=0$

$$ \dfrac{2c}{\phi}\dfrac{dt}{t^2} = \pm d\psi $$

Solving for the path of the photon

$$ \psi=\psi_{\text{o}}\pm\dfrac{2c}{\phi}\left(\dfrac{1}{t_{\text{o}}}-\dfrac{1}{t}\right) $$

We can set $\psi_{\text{o}}=0$ by the choice of coordinates and drop the negative direction

$$ \psi=\dfrac{2c}{\phi}\left(\dfrac{1}{t_{\text{o}}}-\dfrac{1}{t}\right) $$

Where $t$ is the current age of the universe and $t_{\text{o}}$ is the age of the universe at the moment of the emission of the photon.  Here $\psi$ represents the arc angle of the photon traveling around the expanding hypersphere of the universe. A full round trip is $\psi=2\pi$

$$ 2\pi=\dfrac{2c}{\phi}\left(\dfrac{1}{t_{\text{o}}}-\dfrac{1}{t}\right) $$

By solving for $t$ we obtain the time $t_{\text{r}}=t_{2\pi}-t_{\text{o}}$ required for the round trip

$$ t_{\text{r}}=\dfrac{t_{\text{o}}^2}{t_{\infty}-t_{\text{o}}} $$

Where $t_{\infty}$ is the age of the universe, after which a round trip at the speed of light is no longer possible, because the universe is expanding too fast

$$ t_{\infty}=\dfrac{c}{\pi\phi} $$

Finally, for the requirement (C), this metric essentially is in the same form as FLRW, just with a different scale factor, so comparing them should be pretty straightforward.

**EDIT - The Hubble Law**

The instantaneous $(t=const.)$ local coordinate $x$ distance along the direction of $\psi$ from a chosen location at $x_o=0$ is

$$ x=\psi r $$

Where $r$ is the current radius of the universe and $\psi=const.$ in the expansion. We can define the recession speed of the point $x$ relative to $x_o$ as

$$ v=\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\psi\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\psi\,\phi\,t=\dfrac{2x}{t} $$

Where $t$ is the current age of the universe. Thus the Hubble law is

$$ v=Hx=\dfrac{2x}{t} $$

With the Hubble parameter showing the age of the universe as double the Hubble time

$$ H=\dfrac{2}{t} $$

The radius of the observable universe (cosmic horizon) at the time $t_{\text{o}}$ is the distance, from which the photons will never reach back. From the path of the photon above for $t=\infty$ we have

$$ x=\psi r=\dfrac{2cr}{\phi t_{\text{o}}}=ct_{\text{o}} $$

Which matches the intuition. The radius of the universe when at $t_{\infty}$ it becomes larger than the observable universe

$$ r_{\infty}=\dfrac{c^2}{2\pi^2\phi}=\dfrac{\phi}{2}t_{\infty}^2 $$

Comment: "As you can easily see, for ϕ=0 time in this universe stops."  Yes, time stops at $\phi = 0$.  Why is this an issue?  $\phi$ is a positive constant.

Comment: I've moved the followup discussion to [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82153/discussion-on-answer-by-safesphere-how-can-i-trace-the-path-of-a-photon-on-space).